# HPA Implementation on single node kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running Kubernetes cluster on GKE. Running the monolithic application and now migrating to microservices so both are running parallel on cluster.

A monolithic application is simple python app taking the memory of `200Mb` around.

K8s cluster is simple single node cluster GKE having `15Gb memory and 4vCPU`.

Now i am thinking to apply the HPA for my microservices and monolithic application.

On single node i have also installed Graylog stack which include (`elasticsearch, mongoDb, Graylog` pod). Sperated by namespace `Devops`.

In another namespace monitoring there is `Grafana, Prometheus, Alert manager` running.

There is also `ingress controller and cert-manager` running.

Now in default namespace there is another `Elasticsearch` for application use, `Redis, Rabbitmq` running. These all are single pod, Type `statefulsets` or `deployment` with volume.

Now i am thinking to apply the HPA for microservices and application.

Can someone suggest how to add node-pool on GKE and auto scale. When i added node in pool and deleted old node from GCP console whole cluster restarted and service goes down for while.

Plus i am thinking to use the `affinity/anti-affinity` so can someone suggest devide infrastructure and implement HPA.

Comment: For `affinity/anti-affinity`, I would recommend to read https://banzaicloud.com/blog/k8s-affinities/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wording in your question, I suspect that you want to *move* your current workloads to the new pool without disruption.

Since this action represents a *voluntary disruption*, you can start by defining a `PodDisruptionBudget` to [control the number of pods that **can** be evicted in this voluntary disruption operation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/#how-disruption-budgets-work):

> A PDB limits the number of pods of a replicated application that are down simultaneously from voluntary disruptions.

The settings in the PDB depend on your application and your business needs, for a reference on the values to apply, you can check [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/#think-about-how-your-application-reacts-to-disruptions).

Following this, you can `drain` the nodes where your application is scheduled since it will be *"protected"* by the budget and, `drain` uses the [Eviction API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/#the-eviction-api) instead of directly deleting the pods, which should make evictions graceful.

Regarding `Affinity`, I'm not sure how it fits in the beforementioned goal that you're trying to achieve. However, there is an answer of this particular regard [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969331/hpa-implementation-on-single-node-kubernetes-cluster#comment102349386_57969331).